# How can I present the user with a list of printers to choose from in my PowerShell Script?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I'm making a script which assists the end user with printer problems. At one point, the user needs to be able to select from a list of printers on the network to decide which one needs maintenance. I'm trying to integrate this via a list box, but I haven't quite been able to get it to function. Here is the script as it stands (It currently uses read-host to allow the user to type in a printer name.)

```
 net stop spooler

Remove-Item C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\* -Force

net start spooler

get-printer

$PrinterName = Read-Host 'Please Type In The Name Of The Printer Above That You Are Having Problems With'

$PrinterInstance = [wmi]"\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_Printer.DeviceID='$PrinterName'"




try{
$PrinterInstance.PrintTestPage() 
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("I found a problem that I was able to fix.  Please try to print again.",0,"Printer Helper",0x1)
}
catch
{
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("Printer Fixer can not solve your problem, please enter a new ticket.",0,"Printer Helper",0x1)
}
```

Here is the "list box" code that I want to implement.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Select a Computer"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$x=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Please select a computer:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$objListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objListBox.Height = 80

[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-001")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-002")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-003")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-004")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-005")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-006")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-007")

$objForm.Controls.Add($objListBox) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

I tried replacing the hard coded values with `$objListBox.Items.Add(Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Printer | Select Name | ft -auto)`

but wmi.object[] is all that appears in the list box. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to not just select the Name property, you need to expand it, and then get rid of the `ft -auto`. So something like `Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Printer | Select -Expand Name|%{$objListBox.Items.Add($_)}` ...yeah, that would do it. Get a list of printers, expand the Name property, and then for each name add that item to the listbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using forms is very heavy-handed for something like this.

[My recommendation is to use `Out-GridView`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849920.aspx).

It provides a sortable, searchable, filterable list in a pop-up window. But it also lets the user select one or more items and those become the output of the cmdlet.

```
$printerSelection = $printerList | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single
```